# AWS ECS Task - Cannot override CPU

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

i am trying to override the CPU Units for a **ECS** Task in the **RunTask** method of the SDK.

**Task Definition**

```
{
  "ipcMode": null,
  "executionRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::111459517389:role/ecsTaskExecutionRole",
  "containerDefinitions": [
    {
      ...,
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "hostPort": 80,
          "protocol": "tcp",
          "containerPort": 80
        },
        ...
      ],
      "command": null,
      "linuxParameters": null,
      "cpu": 256, # CONTAINER CPU Units (default)
      "environment": [
        {
          "name": "ECS_IMAGE_PULL_BEHAVIOR",
          "value": "prefer-cached"
        }
      ],
      "ulimits": null,
      ...
      "name": "some-job-container"
    }
  ],
  "placementConstraints": [],
  "memory": "8192", # TASK SIZE
  "taskRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::111459517389:role/ecsTaskExecutionRole",
  "compatibilities": [
    "EC2",
    "FARGATE"
  ],
  "taskDefinitionArn": "arn:aws:ecs:eu-west-3:111459517389:task-definition/some-definition:7",
  "family": "some-job-dev",
  "requiresAttributes": [
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.logging-driver.awslogs"
    },
   ...
  ],
  "pidMode": null,
  "requiresCompatibilities": [
    "FARGATE"
  ],
  "networkMode": "awsvpc",
  "cpu": "4096", # TASK SIZE 
  "revision": 7,
  "status": "ACTIVE",
  "inferenceAccelerators": null,
  "proxyConfiguration": null,
  "volumes": []
}
```

And here's the **RunTask** parameters

```
{
   "taskDefinition":"some-job-dev",
   "cluster":"some-cluster",
   "overrides":{
      "containerOverrides":[
         {
            "name":"some-job-container",
            "command":[
               "kosmos",
               "segmentation-queue"
            ],
            "cpu":4092,
            "memory":8192
         }
      ]
   },
   "networkConfiguration":{
      "awsvpcConfiguration":{
         "assignPublicIp":"ENABLED",
         "subnets":[
            "subnet-789",
            "subnet-456",
            "subnet-123"
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

When i run a task with these parameters, the **memory** of the container gets correctly overridden, but not the **CPU**.
I am following the **ECS** Documentation and still it doesn't work, am i missing something here ?

Notes:

- My task launch type is **Fargate**

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, and its intermittent. Were you able to solve it?

I see you are passing values as an int, for me specifying them as a string helped.

Comment: Also.. I think it might be a bug in the AWS interface. If you just call the API you can see the overwrite took effect (1024 instead of 4096 in my case) but in the task "view" page in AWS it still shows 4096.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the cpu and memory values in containerOverrides (as integer) as well as in overrides (as strings of the same integers).
Reference:

1. [boto3](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ecs/client/run_task.html#)
2. [This answer](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ecs/client/run_task.html#) on stackoverflow

I do the following in python and it works:

```
def get_ecs_operator_args(taskDefinitionName, taskContainerName, command, launch_type = "FARGATE", cpu=None, memory=None):
    containerOverrides = {'name': taskContainerName, 'command': command}
    if cpu is not None: containerOverrides['cpu'] = cpu
    if memory is not None: containerOverrides['memory'] = memory
    overrides = {'containerOverrides': [containerOverrides]}
    if cpu is not None: overrides['cpu'] = str(cpu)
    if memory is not None: overrides['memory'] = str(memory)

    config = dict(
        cluster='clustername',
        task_definition=taskDefinitionName,
        launch_type=launch_type,
        overrides=overrides,
        network_configuration={
            'awsvpcConfiguration': {
                'securityGroups': ['sg-'],
                'subnets': ['subnet-'],
                'assignPublicIp': "ENABLED"
            }
        },
        awslogs_group="/ecs/whatever",
        awslogs_stream_prefix="ecs/whatever",  # prefix with container name
    )
    return config
```